# want to call two functions in change and can't pass the event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am trying to call on change(search in an array on objects and give me the id) in the same class and trying to call a function in the context to update the state and pass the object id found alse trying to pass value to the context function

i have tried to make a function that calls on change(in the same class) and call the function in the context but can't pass the event and i get an error in cannot read property target

```
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react'
import {Link} from  'react-router-dom'
import styled from 'styled-components'
// import Seasonal from './Seasonal';
import TopBar from './TopBar'
import {storeProducts}  from '../data';
import { ProductConsumer } from '../context';

export default class NavBar extends Component {

    constructor (props) {
        super();
      }
    state={
        text:'',
        no: 0
    }

    onSubmit = (e) =>{
        this.state.text = e.target.value
        const found = storeProducts.find(function(element) {
            return element.title === e.target.value
          });
          if(found != null){
          this.setState(()=>{
            return (
                this.state.no = found.id,
                console.log(this.state.text)
                )
        })
    }
    else{
        this.state.no = 0;
        console.log(this.state.text)
        console.log(this.state.no)
    }
    }
    contextFun = (e) =>{
        this.onSubmit(),
        thi
        return null
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ProductConsumer>
                    {value => {
                        // const {modalOpen,closeModal}= value;

                    return(
                        <div>
                <TopBar></TopBar>
                <NavWrapper className="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark px-sm-5 justify-content-between">
                    <Link to='/' className="nav-li">
                        <h2 className="text-danger">SHOP MATE</h2>
                    </Link>
                        < ul className="navbar-nav align-items-center">
                            <li className="nav-item ml-5">
                                <Link to="/" className="nav-link">
                                    products
                                </Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item ml-5"> 
                                <Link to="/nature" className="nav-link">
                                    nature
                                </Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item ml-5">
                                <Link to="/seasonal" className="nav-link">
                                    seasonal
                                </Link>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <form className="form-inline">
                <input className="form-control text-danger mr-sm-2" type="search" onChange={this.contextFun(this)} placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search"/>
                {/* <button className="btn btn-outline-danger my-2 my-sm-0" onClick={this.onSubmit}>Search</button> */}

                </form>
                </NavWrapper>
                </div>
                    )

                    }
                    }
                </ProductConsumer>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Consider this:**

```
<input className="form-control text-danger mr-sm-2" type="search" onChange={e => this.contextFun(e)} placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search"/>
```

the syntax `{e => this.contextFun(e)}`, it's an arrow function that recieves the event, it will be called as a callback function for the `onChange` event, it will take the `e`, and pass it to your `contextFun`, which will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

`onChange={this.contextFun(this)}` will invoke `contextFun` on *every* render, and will pass the component as `e` - what you want is `onChange={this.contextFun}`. That would fix the first problem, however you've then got another issue in that inside `contextFun` you call `onSubmit` but don't pass the event object i.e.

```
this.onSubmit(); // should be this.onSubmit(e)
```

`contextFun` is unnecessary, if you change your `onChange` to use `onSubmit` directly, then this would work

```
<input onChange={onSubmit} />
```